# Update only selected Fields and not all the columns in database through hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm working on a project using hibernate for OR mapping with mysql .
I want only nom , telephone, adresse and date_modification to get updated but all the fields are getting updated. i don't know where i went wrong. please help me to figure out this issue. 
Following is action class i have written:

Test.java

```
public class Test {
    static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"applicationContext.xml"});
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ajouterFournisseur("Fournisseur 1", "23421567", "ville 1", "rue 1", "4321");
        ajouterFournisseur("Fournisseur 2", "23421567", "ville 2", "rue 2", "4322");
        ajouterFournisseur("Fournisseur 3", "23421567", "ville 3", "rue 3", "4323");

        modifierFournisseur("1", "1", "Fournisseur 11", "21345678", "Ville 11", "Rue 11", "4212");
        listeFournisseur();
}

    public static void ajouterFournisseur(String nom, String telephone, String ville, String rue, String code_postal) {
            IFournisseurMetier metierFournisseur = (IFournisseurMetier) context.getBean("metierFournisseur");
            IAdresseMetier metierAdresse = (IAdresseMetier) context.getBean("metierAdresse");
            List<Fournisseurs> fournisseurs1 = metierFournisseur.listFournisseurs();
            FournisseurForm fournisseurForm = new FournisseurForm(metierFournisseur);
            AdresseForm adresseForm = new AdresseForm(metierAdresse);
            fournisseurForm.creerFournisseur(nom, telephone, adresseForm.creerAdresse(ville, rue, code_postal));
            List<Fournisseurs> fournisseurs2 = metierFournisseur.listFournisseurs();
            System.out.println("etat ajouter Fournisseur: "+(fournisseurs2.size()==fournisseurs1.size()+3));
    }

private static void modifierFournisseur(String id_fournisseur, String id_adresse, 
            String nom_fournisseur, String telephone, String ville, String rue, String code_postal) {
           IFournisseurMetier metierFournisseur = (IFournisseurMetier) context.getBean("metierFournisseur");
           IAdresseMetier metierAdresse = (IAdresseMetier) context.getBean("metierAdresse");
           FournisseurForm  fournisseurForm = new FournisseurForm(metierFournisseur);
           AdresseForm adresseForm = new AdresseForm(metierAdresse);
           fournisseurForm.modifierFournisseur(id_fournisseur, nom_fournisseur, telephone, adresseForm.modifierAdresse(id_adresse, ville, rue, code_postal));
          if(adresseForm.getErreurs() != null){
            if(adresseForm.getErreurs().get("ville") != null){
                    System.out.println((fournisseurForm.getErreurs().get("ville")));
                }
                if(adresseForm.getErreurs().get("rue") != null){
                    System.out.println((fournisseurForm.getErreurs().get("rue")));
                }
                if(adresseForm.getErreurs().get("code_postal") != null){
                    System.out.println((fournisseurForm.getErreurs().get("code_postal")));
                }
          }
            if((fournisseurForm.getErreurs() != null)){
                if(fournisseurForm.getErreurs().get("nom") != null){
                    System.out.println((fournisseurForm.getErreurs().get("nom")));
                }
                if(fournisseurForm.getErreurs().get("telephone") != null){
                    System.out.println((fournisseurForm.getErreurs().get("telephone")));
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(( fournisseurForm.getResultat()));
            }
    }

private static void listeFournisseur() {
        IFournisseurMetier metierFournisseur = (IFournisseurMetier) context.getBean("metierFournisseur");
        for(Fournisseurs fournisseur : metierFournisseur.listFournisseurs()){
            if(fournisseur!=null)
            System.out.println("Id_fournisseur: "+fournisseur.getId_fournisseur());
            System.out.println("Nom: "+fournisseur.getNom());
            System.out.println("Telephone: "+fournisseur.getTelephone());
            System.out.println("Ville: "+fournisseur.getAdresse().getVille());
            System.out.println("Rue: "+fournisseur.getAdresse().getRue());
            System.out.println("Code postal: "+fournisseur.getAdresse().getCode_postal());
            System.out.println("date d'ajout: "+fournisseur.getDate_ajout());
            System.out.println("date modification: "+fournisseur.getDate_modification());
            System.out.println("-----------------");
        }
    }
}
```

FournisseurDaoImpl.java

```
public class FournisseurDaoImpl implements IFournisseurDao {

    public Long ajouterFournisseur(Fournisseurs fournisseur) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(fournisseur);
        session.beginTransaction().commit();
        return fournisseur.getId_fournisseur();
    }

    public void modifierFournisseur(Fournisseurs fournisseur) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(fournisseur);
        session.beginTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void supprimerFournisseur(Long idFournisseur) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Articles article = (Articles) session.load(Articles.class, idFournisseur);
        session.delete(article);
        session.beginTransaction().commit();
    }

    public List<Fournisseurs> listFournisseurs() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Fournisseurs> result = session.createQuery("from Fournisseurs").list();
        for (Fournisseurs fournisseur : result) {
            Hibernate.initialize(fournisseur.getAdresse());
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return result;
    }
    public Fournisseurs trouverFournisseurParId(Long idFournisseur) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        return (Fournisseurs) session.get(Fournisseurs.class, idFournisseur);
    }

    public Fournisseurs trouverFournisseurParNom(String nom_fournisseur) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Fournisseurs.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("nom", nom_fournisseur));
        return (Fournisseurs) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }

}
```

Result:

```
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@190d1e8: startup date [Fri Nov 11 14:45:41 WAT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@18da386: defining beans [datasource,persistenceUnitManager,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,daoUtilisateur,metierUtilisateur,daoFournisseur,metierFournisseur,daoArticle,metierArticle,daoEntree,metierEntree,daoSortie,metierSortie,daoAdresse,metierAdresse,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Hibernate: select fournisseu0_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_, fournisseu0_.NOM as NOM26_, fournisseu0_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_, fournisseu0_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_, fournisseu0_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_, fournisseu0_.id_adresse as id6_26_ from FOURNISSEURS fournisseu0_
Hibernate: insert into ADRESSE (VILLE, RUE, CODE_POSTAL) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select this_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_0_, this_.NOM as NOM26_0_, this_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_0_, this_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_0_, this_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_0_, this_.id_adresse as id6_26_0_ from FOURNISSEURS this_ where this_.NOM like ?
Hibernate: insert into FOURNISSEURS (NOM, TELEPHONE, DATE_AJOUT, DATE_MODIFICATION, id_adresse) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update ADRESSE set VILLE=?, RUE=?, CODE_POSTAL=? where ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: select fournisseu0_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_, fournisseu0_.NOM as NOM26_, fournisseu0_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_, fournisseu0_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_, fournisseu0_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_, fournisseu0_.id_adresse as id6_26_ from FOURNISSEURS fournisseu0_
Hibernate: select adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_22_1_, adresse0_.VILLE as VILLE22_1_, adresse0_.RUE as RUE22_1_, adresse0_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_22_1_, fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_0_, fournisseu1_.NOM as NOM26_0_, fournisseu1_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_0_, fournisseu1_.id_adresse as id6_26_0_ from ADRESSE adresse0_ left outer join FOURNISSEURS fournisseu1_ on adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR where adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=?
etat ajouter Fournisseur: false
Hibernate: select fournisseu0_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_, fournisseu0_.NOM as NOM26_, fournisseu0_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_, fournisseu0_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_, fournisseu0_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_, fournisseu0_.id_adresse as id6_26_ from FOURNISSEURS fournisseu0_
Hibernate: select adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_22_1_, adresse0_.VILLE as VILLE22_1_, adresse0_.RUE as RUE22_1_, adresse0_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_22_1_, fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_0_, fournisseu1_.NOM as NOM26_0_, fournisseu1_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_0_, fournisseu1_.id_adresse as id6_26_0_ from ADRESSE adresse0_ left outer join FOURNISSEURS fournisseu1_ on adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR where adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: insert into ADRESSE (VILLE, RUE, CODE_POSTAL) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select this_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_0_, this_.NOM as NOM26_0_, this_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_0_, this_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_0_, this_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_0_, this_.id_adresse as id6_26_0_ from FOURNISSEURS this_ where this_.NOM like ?
Hibernate: insert into FOURNISSEURS (NOM, TELEPHONE, DATE_AJOUT, DATE_MODIFICATION, id_adresse) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update ADRESSE set VILLE=?, RUE=?, CODE_POSTAL=? where ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: select fournisseu0_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_, fournisseu0_.NOM as NOM26_, fournisseu0_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_, fournisseu0_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_, fournisseu0_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_, fournisseu0_.id_adresse as id6_26_ from FOURNISSEURS fournisseu0_
Hibernate: select adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_22_1_, adresse0_.VILLE as VILLE22_1_, adresse0_.RUE as RUE22_1_, adresse0_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_22_1_, fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_0_, fournisseu1_.NOM as NOM26_0_, fournisseu1_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_0_, fournisseu1_.id_adresse as id6_26_0_ from ADRESSE adresse0_ left outer join FOURNISSEURS fournisseu1_ on adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR where adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: select adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_22_1_, adresse0_.VILLE as VILLE22_1_, adresse0_.RUE as RUE22_1_, adresse0_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_22_1_, fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_0_, fournisseu1_.NOM as NOM26_0_, fournisseu1_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_0_, fournisseu1_.id_adresse as id6_26_0_ from ADRESSE adresse0_ left outer join FOURNISSEURS fournisseu1_ on adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR where adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=?
etat ajouter Fournisseur: false
Hibernate: select fournisseu0_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_, fournisseu0_.NOM as NOM26_, fournisseu0_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_, fournisseu0_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_, fournisseu0_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_, fournisseu0_.id_adresse as id6_26_ from FOURNISSEURS fournisseu0_
Hibernate: select adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_22_1_, adresse0_.VILLE as VILLE22_1_, adresse0_.RUE as RUE22_1_, adresse0_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_22_1_, fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_0_, fournisseu1_.NOM as NOM26_0_, fournisseu1_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_0_, fournisseu1_.id_adresse as id6_26_0_ from ADRESSE adresse0_ left outer join FOURNISSEURS fournisseu1_ on adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR where adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: select adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_22_1_, adresse0_.VILLE as VILLE22_1_, adresse0_.RUE as RUE22_1_, adresse0_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_22_1_, fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_0_, fournisseu1_.NOM as NOM26_0_, fournisseu1_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_0_, fournisseu1_.id_adresse as id6_26_0_ from ADRESSE adresse0_ left outer join FOURNISSEURS fournisseu1_ on adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR where adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: insert into ADRESSE (VILLE, RUE, CODE_POSTAL) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select this_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_0_, this_.NOM as NOM26_0_, this_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_0_, this_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_0_, this_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_0_, this_.id_adresse as id6_26_0_ from FOURNISSEURS this_ where this_.NOM like ?
Hibernate: insert into FOURNISSEURS (NOM, TELEPHONE, DATE_AJOUT, DATE_MODIFICATION, id_adresse) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update ADRESSE set VILLE=?, RUE=?, CODE_POSTAL=? where ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: select fournisseu0_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_, fournisseu0_.NOM as NOM26_, fournisseu0_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_, fournisseu0_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_, fournisseu0_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_, fournisseu0_.id_adresse as id6_26_ from FOURNISSEURS fournisseu0_
Hibernate: select adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_22_1_, adresse0_.VILLE as VILLE22_1_, adresse0_.RUE as RUE22_1_, adresse0_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_22_1_, fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_0_, fournisseu1_.NOM as NOM26_0_, fournisseu1_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_0_, fournisseu1_.id_adresse as id6_26_0_ from ADRESSE adresse0_ left outer join FOURNISSEURS fournisseu1_ on adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR where adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: select adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_22_1_, adresse0_.VILLE as VILLE22_1_, adresse0_.RUE as RUE22_1_, adresse0_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_22_1_, fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_0_, fournisseu1_.NOM as NOM26_0_, fournisseu1_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_0_, fournisseu1_.id_adresse as id6_26_0_ from ADRESSE adresse0_ left outer join FOURNISSEURS fournisseu1_ on adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR where adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: select adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_22_1_, adresse0_.VILLE as VILLE22_1_, adresse0_.RUE as RUE22_1_, adresse0_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_22_1_, fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_0_, fournisseu1_.NOM as NOM26_0_, fournisseu1_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_0_, fournisseu1_.id_adresse as id6_26_0_ from ADRESSE adresse0_ left outer join FOURNISSEURS fournisseu1_ on adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR where adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=?
etat ajouter Fournisseur: false
Hibernate: select adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_22_0_, adresse0_.VILLE as VILLE22_0_, adresse0_.RUE as RUE22_0_, adresse0_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_22_0_ from ADRESSE adresse0_ where adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: select fournisseu0_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_1_, fournisseu0_.NOM as NOM26_1_, fournisseu0_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_1_, fournisseu0_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_1_, fournisseu0_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_1_, fournisseu0_.id_adresse as id6_26_1_, adresse1_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_22_0_, adresse1_.VILLE as VILLE22_0_, adresse1_.RUE as RUE22_0_, adresse1_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_22_0_ from FOURNISSEURS fournisseu0_ left outer join ADRESSE adresse1_ on fournisseu0_.id_adresse=adresse1_.ID_ADRESSE where fournisseu0_.ID_FOURNISSEUR=?
Hibernate: update ADRESSE set VILLE=?, RUE=?, CODE_POSTAL=? where ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: select this_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_0_, this_.NOM as NOM26_0_, this_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_0_, this_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_0_, this_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_0_, this_.id_adresse as id6_26_0_ from FOURNISSEURS this_ where this_.NOM like ?
Hibernate: update FOURNISSEURS set NOM=?, TELEPHONE=?, DATE_AJOUT=?, DATE_MODIFICATION=?, id_adresse=? where ID_FOURNISSEUR=?
Hibernate: update ADRESSE set VILLE=?, RUE=?, CODE_POSTAL=? where ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: update ARTICLES set ID_FOURNISSEUR=null where ID_FOURNISSEUR=?
Hibernate: select fournisseu0_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_, fournisseu0_.NOM as NOM26_, fournisseu0_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_, fournisseu0_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_, fournisseu0_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_, fournisseu0_.id_adresse as id6_26_ from FOURNISSEURS fournisseu0_
Hibernate: select adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_22_1_, adresse0_.VILLE as VILLE22_1_, adresse0_.RUE as RUE22_1_, adresse0_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_22_1_, fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_0_, fournisseu1_.NOM as NOM26_0_, fournisseu1_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_0_, fournisseu1_.id_adresse as id6_26_0_ from ADRESSE adresse0_ left outer join FOURNISSEURS fournisseu1_ on adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR where adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: select adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_22_1_, adresse0_.VILLE as VILLE22_1_, adresse0_.RUE as RUE22_1_, adresse0_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_22_1_, fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_0_, fournisseu1_.NOM as NOM26_0_, fournisseu1_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_0_, fournisseu1_.id_adresse as id6_26_0_ from ADRESSE adresse0_ left outer join FOURNISSEURS fournisseu1_ on adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR where adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=?
Hibernate: select adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE as ID1_22_1_, adresse0_.VILLE as VILLE22_1_, adresse0_.RUE as RUE22_1_, adresse0_.CODE_POSTAL as CODE4_22_1_, fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR as ID1_26_0_, fournisseu1_.NOM as NOM26_0_, fournisseu1_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_AJOUT as DATE4_26_0_, fournisseu1_.DATE_MODIFICATION as DATE5_26_0_, fournisseu1_.id_adresse as id6_26_0_ from ADRESSE adresse0_ left outer join FOURNISSEURS fournisseu1_ on adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=fournisseu1_.ID_FOURNISSEUR where adresse0_.ID_ADRESSE=?
Id_fournisseur: 1
Nom: Fournisseur 11
Telephone: 21345678
Ville: Ville 11
Rue: Rue 11
Code postal: 4212
date d'ajout: null
date modification: 2016-11-11 14:45:46.0
-----------------
Id_fournisseur: 2
Nom: Fournisseur 2
Telephone: 23421567
Ville: ville 2
Rue: rue 2
Code postal: 4322
date d'ajout: 2016-11-11 14:45:46.0
date modification: 2016-11-11 14:45:46.0
-----------------
Id_fournisseur: 3
Nom: Fournisseur 3
Telephone: 23421567
Ville: ville 3
Rue: rue 3
Code postal: 4323
date d'ajout: 2016-11-11 14:45:46.0
date modification: 2016-11-11 14:45:46.0
-----------------
```

In my console of Eclipse all the fields are getting updated. 
like this:

```
Hibernate: update FOURNISSEURS set NOM=?, TELEPHONE=?, DATE_AJOUT=?, DATE_MODIFICATION=?, id_adresse=? where ID_FOURNISSEUR=?
```

Comment: this defeats the object of hibernate.

Comment: is this mean that we can't find a solution?

Comment: Have you tried to add the annotation [@DynamicUpdate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicUpdate.html) to your entity `Fournisseurs`?

Comment: DynamicUpdate cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
public class FournisseurDaoImpl implements IFournisseurDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
public void modifierFournisseurJPA(Fournisseurs fournisseur) {
        em.merge(fournisseur);
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using hbm.xml you must set the attribute **dynamic-update="true"** in the **class** node. Default is false that's why all columns are updated.

See: 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class

Comment: im not using annotation JPA. im using Fournisseurs.hbm.xml file

Comment: @Column(updatable=false) the same problem

Comment: i tryed dynamic-update="true"  it update the table but it set the column date_ajout to null. i need more help.

Comment: the attribute dynamic-update="true"  is not working.

Answer (score 0):

While calling `modifierFournisseur(Fournisseurs fournisseur)`create a new object of `Fournisseurs` and set Id and the respective field you want to update.

It should update only the field which you set in the attached JPA object.

Comment: after trying modifierFournisseur(Fournisseurs fournisseur) im getting the same problem.